# How do I restore internet connectivity in cloned Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-networking

We cloned a VM (with significant help from an MS tech). It now sits on 52.158.131.150 and is supposed to be the new home for [HOPL](https://hopl.info). However, things aren't going so well.

We've pointed hopl.info to the new IP address, but when I `tracert` to the new address it goes nowhere. Pinging times out. Browsing times out.

When I run the Network Diagnostics from inside the VM I get the following dialog:
[image]. Obviously, power-cycling the broadband modem isn't a thing in this situation. What should I be looking for and where?

Answer (score 0):

Went into the Azure portal, raised a New Support Request (took a while to find the right Service type), [image], filled out the diagnostic panel (funny spelling for diagnostic), [image], and got told that there was a firewall rule blocking traffic. Fixed that and now [HOPL](https://hopl.info) is back online!